# nodejs + sequelize :: include where required false

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i have the following hierarchy of objects:

1. user
2. parent (hasOne)
3. children (hasMany)

once i have a user object, im attempting to load the associated parent object along with **some** of its children. the following works:

```
user.getParent({
  include: [{
    model: Child
  }]
}).then(function(parent) {
  var children = parent.children;
});
```

but if i want to selectively load **some** of the parent's children, like so:

```
user.getParent({
  include: [{
    model: Child,
    where: { gender: 'FEMALE' }
  }]
}).then(function(parent) {
  var daughters = parent.daughters;
});
```

if the parent has one or more daughters, the query works and i get the parent data along with all daughters' data. **however, if the parent has only sons, the parent object returned is `null`**..

i want that if the parent has no daughters, the parent object should still be resolved with `children = null` or `children = []`..

also, if i wanted to simply load a count of children while loading the parent, how can i go about doing that?

thanks

Answer (score 12):

it turned out to be an issue with my own code.. sequelize fails to load a model if a nested include has a `where` clause that returns no models.. to ensure it doesnt fail completely, you can set a `required: false` clause along with the `where` clause.. this makes sequelize return a blank array instead of failing the load completely..

more info at https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4019

Answer (score 1):

**`required: false` + `where` is inconsistent/buggy in sequelize 6.5.1 SQLite vs PostgreSQL**

Edit: it was working fine as of sequelize v6.13.0, so it got fixed somewhere along the way.

This is one of the many many many Sequelize association bugs/inconsistencies that make me want to try and find another ORM at some point. Reported at: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/13809

Consider the following example where we want to:

- list all tags
- in addition, determine if each tag has been assigned to a selected animal

  Our where condition on the animal then is a simple "check if the animal is a specific animal", and can only return 0 or 1 entries therefore. But the same would be valid with any other more complex condition.

main.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const assert = require('assert')
const path = require('path')
const { DataTypes, Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
let sequelize
if (process.argv[2] === 'p') {
  sequelize = new Sequelize('tmp', undefined, undefined, {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: '/var/run/postgresql',
  })
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: 'tmp.sqlite'
  })
}
;(async () => {
const Animal = sequelize.define('Animal', {
  species: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
})
const Tag = sequelize.define('Tag', {
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
})
Animal.belongsToMany(Tag, { through: 'AnimalTag' })
Tag.belongsToMany(Animal, { through: 'AnimalTag' })
await sequelize.sync({force: true})
const animal0 = await Animal.create({ species: 'bat' })
const animal1 = await Animal.create({ species: 'ant' })
const animal2 = await Animal.create({ species: 'dog' })
const tag0 = await Tag.create({ name: 'mammal' })
const tag1 = await Tag.create({ name: 'flying' })
const tag2 = await Tag.create({ name: 'aquatic' })
await animal0.addTag(tag0)
await animal0.addTag(tag1)
await animal2.addTag(tag1)
const animals = [animal0, animal1, animal2]
for (let animal of animals) {
  let rows
  rows = await Tag.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: Animal,
      where: { id: animal.id },
      // No effect.
      //on: { id: animal.id },
      through: {
        // Same as putting the where outside of through.
        //where: { AnimalId: animal.id },
      },
      required: false,
    }],
    order: [['name', 'ASC']],
  })
  console.error(animal.species);
  console.error(rows.map(row => { return {
    name: row.name,
    animals: row.Animals.map(animal => animal.species),
  } }))
}
})().finally(() => { return sequelize.close() })
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "8.5.1",
    "pg-hstore": "2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "6.5.1",
    "sqlite3": "5.0.2"
  }
}
```

Run:

```
npm install
./main.js p
./main.js
```

The PotsgreSQL results are as expected:

```
bat
[
  { name: 'aquatic', animals: [] },
  { name: 'flying', animals: [ 'bat' ] },
  { name: 'mammal', animals: [ 'bat' ] }
]

ant
[
  { name: 'aquatic', animals: [] },
  { name: 'flying', animals: [] },
  { name: 'mammal', animals: [] }
]

dog
[
  { name: 'aquatic', animals: [] },
  { name: 'flying', animals: [] },
  { name: 'mammal', animals: [ 'dog' ] }
]
```

But the SQLite results are just plain wrong:

```
bat
[
  { name: 'aquatic', animals: [] },
  { name: 'flying', animals: [ 'bat' ] },
  { name: 'mammal', animals: [ 'bat', null ] }
]

ant
[
  { name: 'aquatic', animals: [] },
  { name: 'flying', animals: [] },
  { name: 'mammal', animals: [] }
]

dog
[
  { name: 'aquatic', animals: [] },
  { name: 'flying', animals: [] },
  { name: 'mammal', animals: [] }
]
```

I don't mind the `null` that much, I can work around that.

But `dog` not being a `mammal`, that I cannot work around.

**Underlying queries**

We can look at the underlying queries to guess what is going on.

PostgreSQL has queries of type:

```
SELECT
  "Tag"."name",
  "Animals"."species" AS "Animals.species",
FROM
  "Tags" AS "Tag"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    "AnimalTag" AS "Animals->AnimalTag"
    INNER JOIN "Animals" AS "Animals" ON "Animals"."id" = "Animals->AnimalTag"."AnimalId"
  ) ON "Tag"."id" = "Animals->AnimalTag"."TagId"
  AND "Animals"."id" = 1
ORDER BY
  "Tag"."name" ASC;
```

SQLite has queries of type:

```
SELECT
 `Tag`.`name`,
 `Animals`.`species` AS `Animals.species`
FROM `Tags` AS `Tag`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `AnimalTag` AS `Animals->AnimalTag`
  ON `Tag`.`id` = `Animals->AnimalTag`.`TagId`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Animals` AS `Animals`
  ON `Animals`.`id` = `Animals->AnimalTag`.`AnimalId`
  AND `Animals`.`id`= 3
ORDER BY
 `Tag`.`name` ASC;
```

So only the PostgreSQL query is the desired one because of the way it uses the subquery so that the:

```
ON "Tag"."id" = "Animals->AnimalTag"."TagId"
  AND "Animals"."id" = 1
```

gets applied only to the outer `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

The SQLite query produces undesired results, running it manually for each animal we get outputs:

```
bat

aquatic|
flying|bat
mammal|bat
mammal|

ant

aquatic|
flying|
mammal|
mammal|

dot

aquatic|
flying|
mammal|
mammal|dog
```

so what seems to happen is that the animal first result is null, then sequelize ignores it on the return, which would explain why we saw:

```
  { name: 'mammal', animals: [ 'bat', null ] }
```

for bat but:

```
  { name: 'mammal', animals: [] }
```

for dog.

The desired statement would have the `AND` on the first `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
 `Tag`.`name`,
 `Animals`.`species` AS `Animals.species`
FROM `Tags` AS `Tag`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `AnimalTag` AS `Animals->AnimalTag`
  ON `Tag`.`id` = `Animals->AnimalTag`.`TagId`
  AND `Animals->AnimalTag`.`AnimalId`= 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Animals` AS `Animals`
  ON `Animals`.`id` = `Animals->AnimalTag`.`AnimalId`
ORDER BY
 `Tag`.`name` ASC;
```

**Workaround: super many to many**

The best workaround I could come up so far is to use super many to many, this is often a good bet when the problem is that we need greater control about `ON` conditions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const assert = require('assert')
const path = require('path')
const { DataTypes, Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
let sequelize
let logging = process.argv[3] === '1'
if (process.argv[2] === 'p') {
  sequelize = new Sequelize('tmp', undefined, undefined, {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: '/var/run/postgresql',
    logging,
  })
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: 'tmp.sqlite',
    logging,
  })
}
;(async () => {
const AnimalTag = sequelize.define('AnimalTag')
const Animal = sequelize.define('Animal', {
  species: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
})
const Tag = sequelize.define('Tag', {
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
})
AnimalTag.belongsTo(Animal)
Animal.hasMany(AnimalTag)
AnimalTag.belongsTo(Tag)
Tag.hasMany(AnimalTag)
Animal.belongsToMany(Tag, { through: AnimalTag })
Tag.belongsToMany(Animal, { through: AnimalTag })

await sequelize.sync({force: true})
const animal0 = await Animal.create({ species: 'bat' })
const animal1 = await Animal.create({ species: 'ant' })
const animal2 = await Animal.create({ species: 'dog' })
const tag0 = await Tag.create({ name: 'flying' })
const tag1 = await Tag.create({ name: 'mammal' })
const tag2 = await Tag.create({ name: 'aquatic' })
await animal0.addTag(tag0)
await animal0.addTag(tag1)
await animal2.addTag(tag1)
const animals = [animal0, animal1, animal2]
for (let animal of animals) {
  let rows
  rows = await Tag.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: AnimalTag,
      where: { AnimalId: animal.id },
      required: false,
      include: [{
        model: Animal,
      }]
    }],
    order: [['name', 'ASC']],
  })
  console.error(rows.map(row => { return {
    name: row.name,
    animals: row.AnimalTags.map(animalTag => animalTag.Animal.species)
  } }))
  console.error();
}
})().finally(() => { return sequelize.close() })
```

produces the correct output for both PostgreSQL and Sequelize. The produced query is exactly what we wanted:

```
SELECT
  "Tag"."id",
  "Tag"."name",
  "Tag"."createdAt",
  "Tag"."updatedAt",
  "AnimalTags"."createdAt" AS "AnimalTags.createdAt",
  "AnimalTags"."updatedAt" AS "AnimalTags.updatedAt",
  "AnimalTags"."AnimalId" AS "AnimalTags.AnimalId",
  "AnimalTags"."TagId" AS "AnimalTags.TagId",
  "AnimalTags->Animal"."id" AS "AnimalTags.Animal.id",
  "AnimalTags->Animal"."species" AS "AnimalTags.Animal.species",
  "AnimalTags->Animal"."createdAt" AS "AnimalTags.Animal.createdAt",
  "AnimalTags->Animal"."updatedAt" AS "AnimalTags.Animal.updatedAt"
FROM
  "Tags" AS "Tag"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "AnimalTags" AS "AnimalTags" ON "Tag"."id" = "AnimalTags"."TagId"
  AND "AnimalTags"."AnimalId" = 3
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "Animals" AS "AnimalTags->Animal" ON "AnimalTags"."AnimalId" = "AnimalTags->Animal"."id"
ORDER BY
  "Tag"."name" ASC;
```

Tested on Ubuntu 21.10, PostgreSQL 13.5.